# Unable to unset a layout constraint in RubyMotion using Motion-Kit gem

Tags: ios, ruby, autolayout, rubymotion, ios-autolayout

I'm having the following scenario.
In one case i need to layout an element to the left of the view, in another case the same view needs to be rendered to the right of the view. The two constraints are conflicting obviosuly.

```
def action_style
   diameter = rmq.device.width*0.06
   constraints do
     width.is diameter
     height.is diameter
     center_y :image
   end
   reapply do
     constraints do
       offset = rmq.device.width*0.08
       if self.even
         left.is 20
       else
         right.is -offset
       end
     end
   end
end
```

`Left` and `Right` are conflicting and i am not getting desired results. Is there any way to disable for example only the `left` constraint or disable/unset all constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not succeed in unsetting/removing a constraint property.
For the time being i fixed it by referencing the left property and changing its value when needed.

```
  def action_style
    diameter = rmq.device.width*0.06
    offset = rmq.device.width*0.08

    constraints do
      width.is diameter
      height.is diameter
      center_y :image
      @left = left.is offset
    end

    reapply do
      constraints do
        if self.even
          @left.constant = offset
        else
          @left.constant = rmq.device.width/2-offset-diameter
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hey it's me!  Sorry I couldn't reply to your github issue in a timely fashion, glad Jamon was able to help out... anyway I think this approach is better.

I'm going to try to add a `remove` method to the MK::Constraint class to make removing them a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend re-setting your constraints entirely.

```
 def action_style
   diameter = rmq.device.width * 0.06
   reapply do
     target.removeConstraints(target.constraints)
     constraints do
       width.is diameter
       height.is diameter
       center_y :image
       offset = rmq.device.width * 0.08
       if self.even
         left.is 20
       else
         right.is -offset
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: I now moved all the setting of the constraints to inside the `reapply` block and unsetted them the way you provided. But when running `reapply!` on the layout a couple of times with different styling the conflicts emerge again. How is this possible?